findOne de mongoose me tira un error extraño
Tengo una api en express typescript con mongoose para una biblioteca y tengo un método que devolvería un libro segun el titulo de este. El problema es que al hacer el GET request, me tira este error:
  "error": "Error fetching book: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"titulo\" (type string) at path \"_id\" for model \"Libro\""
} 

Esta es la funcion que da error:
async function getTitle(titulo: string) {
  try {
    const libro = await Libro.findOne({ 'titulo': titulo }).exec();
    return libro;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`Error fetching book ID: ${error.message}`);
  }
}

Este es el schema:
const LibroSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    titulo: {type: String, required: true},
    autor: {type: String, required: true},
    editorial: {type: String, required: true},
    fecha: {type: String, required: true},
    paginas: {type: Number, required: true},
    prestado: {type: Boolean, required: true},
    imagen: {type: String, required: true}
});

según tengo entendido, se debería poder hacer esto con el findOne, pero no me funciona

Como es el nombre del libro? O sucede con todos? Temas de acento y collages ya evaluaste?? Lee este link

¿Intentante pasar la clave titulo sin las comillas? ({ titulo: titulo })

Me parece que el error no está en la función, sino en el controlador y / o rutas. Es probable que creas estar consumiendo el endpoint para titulo, y estás realmente consumiendo el endpoint para busqueda por ID. Si puedes añadir más detalles a tu pregunta podríamos hallar el problema. De momento te dejo este comentario como pista. Saludos
